# How fast or slow is the Constant memory that Numba allows a device to allocate, when compared to local and shared memories?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, cuda, numba, numba-pro

I can't find any clarity as to what is the performance of the so called Constant memory referred to in the Numba documentation:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/memory.html#constant-memory

I am curious as to what are the size limits for this memory, how fast/slow it is when compared to other memory types and if there are any pitfalls using it.

Thank you!

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/kernels.html#further-reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a general question regarding the constant memory in a CUDA-capable device. You can find info in the official CUDA programming guide and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#constant-memory) in which it says:

> There is a total of 64 KB constant memory on a device. The constant
> memory space is cached. As a result, a read from constant memory costs
> one memory read from device memory only on a cache miss; otherwise, it
> just costs one read from the constant cache. Accesses to different
> addresses by threads within a warp are serialized, thus the cost
> scales linearly with the number of unique addresses read by all
> threads within a warp. As such, the constant cache is best when
> threads in the same warp accesses only a few distinct locations. If
> all threads of a warp access the same location, then constant memory
> can be as fast as a register access.

Regarding how this compares to other memory types, here is my short answer. You may want to read [this page](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#device-memory-spaces) for further details:

- **Registers**: Thread private on-chip read + write memory which can be considered as the fastest memory space on a GPU.
- **Local memory**: Thread private off-chip read + write memory which, despite its misleading name, is physically the same location as global memory. Hence, its high latency.
- **Global memory**: The largest memory with a high latency and a *global* scope which is also off-chip with read + write permissions.
- **Constant memory**: Off-chip cached read-only memory limited to 64 KB which could be accessed by threads as fast as registers,  if all threads of a warp access the same location.
- **Shared memory**: On-chip, low-latency, read + write with limited space per multiprocessor (48 KB to 164 KB depending on the compute capability of your device).
- **Texture memory**: On-chip cached read-only memory optimized for 2D spatial locality that supports unique features like hardware filtering.
- **Pinned (page-locked) memory**: Not an explicit device memory. Accessible directly by both CPU and GPU codes, used to maximize and overlap data transfer between CPU/GPU.

These memories have different scopes, life-times and usages. The Numba page that you have mentioned in your question explains the basics but the official CUDA programming guide has a lot more details. At the end of the day, the answer to the question of when to use each memory is to a large degree application-dependent.